# Root.ts2 not loaded

Tags: typo3, neoscms, typoscript2

I kickstarted a new package and created a new node type which I am able to use in the backend. This is working so far. :)

Then I created the required **Root.ts2** file but **this file never gets loaded!** Why?

The file is placed under Resources/Private/TypoScript as all the other Root.ts2 files.

The Neos version I am using is 1.2 beta.

Answer (score 0):

Try to include this file in your site directly (`Packages/Sites/My.Site/Resources/Private/TypoScript/Root.ts2`) like that:

```
include: resource://My.Package/Private/TypoScript/Root.ts2
```